# Empty $_GET despite the URL

Tags: php

`$_GET` variable shows empty on the URL `www.abc.com/ec/basket.php?product_id=1`.

This is very surprising as `$_GET` does show value on a different domain with the same URL on the same server. Of course the code is a copy of the original domain.

I am baffled as to why is this happening. Even the first line of the code shows blank `$_GET`.

When I did `print_r($_SERVER)` on the first line of the page, I get the following response. The first two values are surprising.

```
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS] => 404
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 404
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.abc.com
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.27 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.712.0 Safari/534.27
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => [various values]
    [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at www.abc.com Port 80


    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
    [SERVER_NAME] => www.abc.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => [IP address]
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => [IP address]
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/htdocs
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@abc.com
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/htdocs/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 39746
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /page-not-found.html
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /ec/basket.html?product_id=1
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [PHP_AUTH_USER] => 
    [PHP_AUTH_PW] => 
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1301662577
)
```

HTTP status on this shows 404 but the page comes up properly. Just that I am not able to get any values in the `$_GET` variable.

Also the `$_GET` variable works perfectly fine on other pages on the same site.

I have been scratching my head on this since hours but cannot find a solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `[REQUEST_URI] => /ec/basket.html?product_id=1`? Why ".html"?

Comment: Looking at the variables, this is saying that the request was for `/ec/basket.html?product_id=1` and was redirected to `/page-not-found.html`... but the current file doing the processing is `/index.php`... confusing to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just have a look to your `.htaccess` file and look more precisely the line containing the `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is probably missing the query string append flag.

Find the line that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule somestuff index.php [L]
```

Replace it with:

```
RewriteRule somestuff index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess file. This will work then.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}                     ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/ec/basket.html?$                  index.php%1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Your script or apache does a redirection without passing the **GET** variables (query string).

Comment: I tried using this but did not help. RewriteRule in the .htaccess file now reads RewriteRule ^((.*).html|(.*).rss|^(\d+)$|(.*)/$) /index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]. Another strange thing is that a copy of the same website on the same server works absolutely fine. And this same code used to work until a few days back.